# Create jar dependency with their lib

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jar, dependencies

How to export a jar (not executable jar) that include the lib which we used to write the code 
Note: I don't use maven

Comment: Use Maven (or Gradle). The term you're looking for is "fat jar", by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't cause I'm working with private dependency

Comment: What build system do you use then?

Comment: i don't use any build system